# Prolog - finding all combinations (The product) of List of Lists (of Lists)

Tags: prolog, combinations, prolog-findall

I'v tried a few features to implement a predicate which finds all the combinations, like in that example:

```
List = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

These should be the output,

```
Comb = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]
```

but all the solutions I've found were using `findall` which I don't want to use in my task.

How can I differently implement the predicate, avoiding `findall` ?

Or maybe how can I implement `my_findall` without using any built-in features?

[A solution like here, without built-in predicates would be great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239662/combinatios-in-list-of-lists-prolog)

Thanks to the helpers!

Comment: Are you allowed to use `member/2`?

Comment: yes, memer I can use. But it is also very esy for implementation, so it isnt a problem at all.

Comment: That's strictly speaking *not* all combinations. Here you calculate the *product*.

Comment: yes, you right, my bad, I meant the product, that's a true correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not so sure this is the most efficient approach, but it's fairly transparent. The idea here is to define the problem in recursive (or inductive) "layers":

```
% multiply_lists(ListOfLists, MultipliedListOfLists)
%
% The first two clauses handle the case where ListOfLists consists
%   of just one list
% The third clause handles the general case
%
multiply_lists([[X]], [[X]]).
multiply_lists([[X|Xs]], [[X]|T]) :- 
    multiply_lists([Xs], T).
multiply_lists([E|Es], R) :-
    multiply_lists(Es, R1),
    multiply_list(E, R1, R).

% multiply_list relates the product of a list of lists and a single list
%    of elements
%
multiply_list([], _, []).
multiply_list([E|Es], L, Ls) :-
    multiply_list(Es, L, LL),
    multiply_element(E, L, LL, Ls).

% multiply_element relates the product, prepended to a given list,
%   of a single list of lists and a single element 
%
multiply_element(_, [], A, A).
multiply_element(X, [Y|Ys], A, [[X|Y]|T]) :-
    multiply_element(X, Ys, A, T).
```

`multiply_element/4` actually combines two rules into one: it defines multiplication of a list by a single element, and prepends those results as individual elements to a given list.

A sample result:

```
| ?- multiply_lists([[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], L).

L = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]] ? ;

no
| ?- multiply_lists([[a,b,c], [1,2], [x,y]], L).

L = [[a,1,x],[a,1,y],[a,2,x],[a,2,y],[b,1,x],[b,1,y],[b,2,x],[b,2,y],[c,1,x],[c,1,y],[c,2,x],[c,2,y]] ? ;

no
```

Some quirks with the above implementation:

- It's not tail recursive (so will use more stack as the lists get longer)
- It leaves a choice point

But it does illustrate how the problem can be solved without using `append/3` or other list-based pre-defined predicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the implementation of findall from "The Craft of Prolog". But in any way you will end up using built-in meta predicates.

So regarding your [linked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239662/combinatios-in-list-of-lists-prolog)

```
try([],[]).
try([L|Ls],[M|Ms]):-
  member(M,L),
  try(Ls,Ms).

findall2( Template, Enumerator, List ) :-
  asserta( 'find all'( [] ) ),
  call( Enumerator ),
  asserta( 'find all'( {Template} ) ),
  fail
;
  all_found( [], List ).


all_found( SoFar, List ) :-
  retract('find all'( Item ) ),
  !,
  /*  to stop retract looking for more Items.  */
  all_found( Item, SoFar, List ).


all_found( [], List, List ).

all_found( {Template}, SoFar, List ) :-
  all_found( [Template|SoFar], List ).
```

So you will get

```
?- List = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], findall2(M,try(List,M),Comb).
List = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]],
Comb = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]].
```

Comment: Of course, but i'm looking a solution, without meta predicates and such stuff. Right now i'm implementing it by a few recursions and some aux predicates.

Comment: By using an aux predicate that can combine 2 lists.